# Difference between ++variable and variable++

Tags: java

When I execute this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 int h=0;
 int g=0;
 for(int j=0;j<10;j++){
     System.out.println(++g+" "+ h++);
 }
```

The Console Prints:

```
1 0

2 1

3 2

4 3

5 4

6 5

7 6

8 7

9 8

10 9
```

Can somebody explain me why the `++g` "increases faster than `h++`?

Comment: There are **many** QA in SO on post or pre increment.

Comment: Both are pre-increment and both print the same value each line.

Comment: The code isn't even consistent with the question...

Comment: but why does it prints like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look to the other answers for what each  ++ does (post or pre increment). ++ is "faster" therefore because it increments before executing the statement, which means it will start on a higher number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have a typo in your print line statement so I will answer your question on ++g and h++.

++g is a pre-increment. h++ is a post-increment.

Pre-increment will add 1 to the value of g before using it. Post-increment will add 1 to the value of h after using it.

Answer (score 1):

Post Increment(variable++) : First execute the statement then increase the value by one.
Pre Increment (++variable) : First increase the value by one then execute the statement.

For  `System.out.println(++g+" "+ ++h);` this the output is of

```
1  1
2  2
  .
  .
  .
```

this format.